# Filter results by a search term

Tags: javascript

The below code filters my `contacts` according to a search term the user typed.

Is there a way I can avoid explicitly writing all the object keys but keep the readability?

```
  contacts = contacts.filter(
    contact =>
      contact.firstName.toLowerCase().includes(search) ||
      contact.lastName.toLowerCase().includes(search) ||
      contact.title.toLowerCase().includes(search) ||
      contact.type.toLowerCase().includes(search) ||
      contact.notes.toLowerCase().includes(search) ||
      contact.phones.filter(val =>
        val.value.toLowerCase().includes(search)
      ).length ||
      contact.emails.filter(val =>
        val.value.toLowerCase().includes(search)
      ).length
  )
```

Comment: When you say "dynamic", are you looking for a way to make this code more flexible (i.e. usable in other contexts)? If so, could you expound a bit on what you're looking for?

Comment: @ScottyJamison I meant to avoid explicitly writing all the object keys

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Object.entries(obj)` and `Array.isArray(obj)` to make it generic:

```js
let testObj = obj => obj.toLowerCase().includes(search);
contacts = contacts.filter(
  contact => Object.entries(contact).some(entry => {
    let [key, value] = entry;
    if (Array.isArray(value)) {
      return value.some(val => testObj(val.value));
    } else {
      return testObj(value);
    }
  });
);
```

If you run the code above with the following sample data:

```js
let contacts = [
  {
    phones: [
        {value: "8765"}, 
        {value: "4356"}
    ],
    foo: "hey",
      bar: "adggg"
  },
  {
    phones: [
        {value: "1234"}, 
        {value: "3456"}
    ],
    foo: "oh",
    bar: "sdff"
  },
  {
    phones: [
        {value: "8765"}, 
        {value: "4356"}
    ],
    foo: "ah",
    bar: "hhh"
  } 
];
let search = "ah";
```

you get:

```js
{
  phones: [
      {value: "8765"}, 
      {value: "4356"}
  ],
  foo: "ah",
  bar: "hhh"
}
```

Comment: Your code will not run if used in modules or strict mode. Always declare variable.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of a few ways:

1. Serialize the whole object. A simple version: `JSON.stringify(contact).toLowerCase().includes(search)`
   This will absolutely get the wrong answer if the user searches for quotes, colons or braces, but if this is not a concern, it will be easy.
2. To be a little more precise, you're going to have to do a little "meta-programming" to get the names of the fields of your object. `Object.keys(contract)` will give you an array of all the keys, which you can then iterate through. You'll need to partition these into two groups: those that are simple strings, and those that are nested arrays. You can then re-work the code you have to use these more generic lists.
3. As your code grows, this will probably be your best path: Create a list of the valid field names; this "data dictionary" can be shared in such a way that they can be used here in a generic way. It could be something as simple as `SEARCHABLE_CONTACT_FIELDS = ['firstName','lastName','title'...` or a more complex `SEARCHABLE_CONTACT_FIELDS = { firstName: 'String', lastName: 'String', phone: 'Array', ...` This gives you more control and this "meta" information will be useful for other functions as well.